# Nginx Cache file is too small

Tags: nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried enabling Nginx caching in my Elastic Beanstalk application. For this matter I've added the following lines in my Nginx configuration file -

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp levels=1:2 keys_zone=analytics-cache:50m max_size=1g inactive=5m use_temp_path=off;
proxy_cache           analytics-cache;
```

The problem is that once I start up Nginx I get the following error in the error.log - `cache file "/tmp/restore_docker_image_names.sh" is too small`.

I have no idea what this error means, and it persisted even after trying to increase the size of my cache key from 5m to 50m. 
How can I avoid this error?

Comment: How come it thinks `restore_docker_image_names.sh` is a cache file? Is there a mention of this file name somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that nginx is trying to open a `.sh` file for it's cache looks suspicious. `/tmp` is used by the whole system so non cache files already exist there.

Use a `proxy_cache_path` that is empty and only nginx will use, like `/tmp/nginx/cache` or `/var/cache/nginx`

Comment: Thanks, that was the thing indeed, now for all the other errors that popped up.

Comment: @YaronIdan But I already getting same error even using a dedidcated path `/var/cache/nginx/` for nginx cache.